# Temporarily redirect mail deliveries

Tags: domain-name-system, email

We used to have our mail and web server on the same machine, so that

- mail for user@example.com
- web requests for www.example.com

would be directed to machine A.

We've moved the web server to machine B, and updated the DNS entry (a complicated process we can't perform ourselves), but now mail is also pointing to B. Presumably because that's the default. While we get the DNS record fixed, is there a way to temporarily tell machine B to redirect mail requests to machine A?

Something quick would be ideal. Preferably without having to install a whole mail server on machine B

Answer (score 0):

Set up Postfix as a backup MX on machine B, it is easy and quick to do.

http://www.howtoforge.com/postfix_backup_mx